# Terminal engaged while using gedit or firefox

Tags: command-line

When I launch gedit or firefox from a terminal, the terminal is occupied(by occupied I mean no other commands can be run from the same terminal window) untill I press ctrl+c but it kills gedit or firefox. Any way other than opening a new terminal window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the applications into the background with the & ...

```
firefox &
```

If you want to re-direct error messages and close the terminal leaving the applications running,

```
nohup firefox > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: yes...nohup worked.

Answer (score 1):

As per http://www.linuxandlife.com/2012/07/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-terminal.html follow the command to launch the app with an ampersand, e.g.:

`firefox &`

`gedit &`

Following the command with the ampersand launches the app then returns cursor control to the terminal window immediately so you are free to run another command within that window.

Comment: That will not work, the commands will hang until you exit firefox

Comment: I don't want to run multiple commands...it is that when i use the command gedit the terminal is occupied and can't take any other command until is press ctrl+c and when i press ctrl+c the program gedit gets killed as well. So i wanted to know is there any other ways of doing that without opening another terminal window...??

Comment: No, not && , just a single &. If you use && or || , that is something else. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510640/command-line-what-is-the-purpose-of